# Media queries showing up differently on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to make my website somewhat responsive by using media queries however they don't seem to be working.

Here is what it is supposed to look liked:

http://mobt.me/3tPS

And here is the actual website:

http://sandbox.rdonohue.ca/

But when I pull up the actual website on my phone I see the full website except the websites name is centered.  I searched for the media query for iPhone 5 so I could see what it looks like but like I said it doesn't appear to be working.

Here is my CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px){

.titleName {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.landingImage {
    height: 200px
}

.mainContentTitle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainContentTitle h5 {
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.mainContentSnippet {
    width: 90%;
}

}
```

Ryan

Comment: You don't have the viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the iPhone5 media query:
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)

You may also need to target the pixel density as well for retina screens:
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5
min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5
-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2

Also double check that there is no css after the media query that would override it.

Comment: I added this and nothing changed.

Then I added 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


And it looks different on my phone but not the same as the view.  Do I need a different viewport?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, however here is the viewport I use in general:  width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0  -- You may also want to look into using a fluid/liquid design: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Comment: I got it working with the viewport!  Thanks so much!  Definitely going to look into liquid design too.